# OnClick Function not attaching fast enough

Tags: javascript, onclick, browserify, require

We are using require to load our JavaScript files that attach a function to button click. I have been able to trace down the issue to require is loading the javascript files asynchronously and it is just taking time for the files to load and start executing .We are thinking about switching from Require to Browserify so that all of the files are compiled into one large file. Would switching to browserify really solve the problem ?

Comment: Well what do you want us to help you with?...

Comment: Start your page with the buttons disabled. Enable them when you attach the click handler.

Comment: we can't do that because we don't know when the buttons will get the function attached.

Comment: ?? Put the enabler to the same function, which attaches click events ...?

Comment: We are just doing $("#buttonId").on("click",function(){})